# Google cloud does not replaice the instance inside the stateful manages instance group

Tags: stateful

A managed instance group created with below code, but when "replace VMS", got this error:

```
Failed to update instance group ssv-node-igm: UpdatePolicy with type set to PROACTIVE and replacementMethod different than RECREATE is not allowed when Stateful is used (instanceGroupManager has statefulPolicy or perInstanceConfigs). Set replacementMethod to RECREATE to apply this update.
```

Also the MIG does not replace the VM failed on health check, but giving "**Instance is being verified**" for more than 6 hours.

The code:

```
  resource "google_compute_health_check" "autohealing" {
    name                = "${var.name_space}-ssv-health-check"
    check_interval_sec  = 5
    timeout_sec         = 5
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 10
  
    tcp_health_check {
      port = "13000"
    }
  }
  
  resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "ssv-node" {
    name = "ssv-node-igm"
  
    base_instance_name = "${var.name_space}-ssv-node"
    zone               = "us-central1-a"
  
    version {
      instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.ssv-template.id
      name              = "${var.name_space}-ssv-node-igm-v1"
    }
  
    target_size = 1
  
    stateful_disk {
      device_name = "${var.name_space}-boot"
    }
  
    stateful_disk {
      device_name = "${var.name_space}-data"
    }
  
  
    named_port {
      name = "customhttp"
      port = 8888
    }
  
    auto_healing_policies {
      health_check      = google_compute_health_check.autohealing.id
      initial_delay_sec = 30
    }
  
    update_policy {
      type               = "PROACTIVE"
      minimal_action     = "REPLACE"
      max_surge_fixed    = 0
      max_unavailable_fixed = 1
      replacement_method = "RECREATE"
    }
  }
```

You can find that update policy is exactly same as what error message suggest to do, but still get same error.

Appricate any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I had a ticket with Google support, and the issue was GUI issue. With below cli, it works.

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed rolling-action replace my-mig
```

Beyond that, another note for anyone using healthcheck: You have to have an health status before the MIG can terminate unhealthy instances. In another word, if your instance never reached health status, it will keep forever.